# What's wrong in this Dedekind cut inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have been trying to understand why the additive inverse of a dedekind cut $\alpha$ has to be
$$\beta=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : \exists r>0 \text{ with} -p-r \notin \alpha\}$$
For that, I decided to consider a simple example,

Let $\alpha=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : p<2\}$

Then shouldn't the inverse be just $\beta=\{q \in \mathbb{Q}:q<-2\}$?

Point out if there is something wrong in my inverse. Also please tell how can i build from my example towards the general inverse of a dedekind cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every Dedekind cut can be constructed in the form

$$ \alpha=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : p < \theta\} $$

where $\theta$ is a known constant.
You might be able to do such a construction for $\theta \in \mathbb Q,$
but to construct the Dedekind cut of an irrational number this way
would be circular. (Where do you get $\theta$ from?)

The construction
$$\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : \exists r>0 \text{ with} -p-r \notin \alpha\}$$
works for any Dedekind cut $\alpha,$ not just for the ones you can construct by writing $ \alpha=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : p < \theta\}. $